# Find equation of tangent to a curve.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to solve this question but encounter problem...

A curve has equation $x^2+y^2=r^2$. The point $P(a,b)$ is a point on the curve. Work out the equation of the tangent to the curve at $P$.

$$x^2+y^2=r^2\tag1$$
To find the coordinate of $P$ we sub into $(1)$

$$P(a,b)=P(\sqrt{r^2-a^2},\sqrt{r^2-b^2})$$

From the centre,O, to point $P$ is the coordinate $(\sqrt{r^2-a^2},\sqrt{r^2-b^2})$

So the gradient of the line $OP={\sqrt{r^2-b^2}\over \sqrt{r^2-a^2}}$

I am stuck at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinate of point $P(a,b)$ is just $(a,b)$.

The radius is perpendicular to the tangent.

Assuming $a \neq 0$ and $b \neq 0$, the gradient of the line connecting the origin to point $(a,b)$ is $\frac{b}{a}$, then the slope of the tangent would be $-\frac{b}{a}$.

Hence the gradient of the tangent is $-\frac{b}{a}$. So now I have told you the gradient of the tangent and you know it passes through $(a,b)$, can you find the equation of the tangent?

Also, can you see the solution if $a=0$? what about when $b=0$?

Remark about your attempt:

if point $(a,b)$ lies on the curve, then they satisfy $a^2+b^2=r^2$, and $a=\pm \sqrt{r^2-b^2}$.